# Best system configuration for Android

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm buying new laptop I fed up with my pc,  AVD loads slowly in my pc so I'm buying new laptop what configuration should I have for my Android application development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run a Surface Pro with an Intel i5, 4GB of RAM, integrated chipset and run things just fine.

I also develop on a late 2011 MacBook Pro. Granted, I don't use the built in emulator and just run my application on my phone. I feel these are some bare minimum specs that you can somewhat comfortably develop with.

Comment: How about Intel i7 with 4gb ram.

Comment: That should be okay. Your bottleneck would be the RAM, then. For futureproofing, and for simplicity, I'd suggest perhaps 8gb RAM and at least an i5.